# Can I write a query that returns all the values from a fixed list that are not in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a list of integers.

```cs
int[] keys = { 14, 27, 32, 34 };
```

Is there a way to construct an Entity Framework query such that I find which, if any, of these integers does not equal the `Id` column in any row of my `Users` table? And I'd like to do this without actually loading any of the `Users` records.

So, for example, if my `Users` table contains the following data:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | Bob Harrison |
| 14 | Sam Shephard |
| 32 | Bill Robinson |
| 33 | Susan Wilson |
| 34 | Gary Wright |

I would want the results to be `{ 27 }`, because only one key value was not in the list of user IDs.

Is this possible without loading any rows from the `Users` table?

Comment: Are those lists fairly long usually (like hundrets, thousands?) or just a couple entries? If they _are_ long, it may be worth thinking about an outer join and select for "orphan" entries.

Comment: @Fildor: They are manageable now. But I just don't have a lot of clear information on how big they might grow.

Answer (score 3):

You will possibly need to query some data from the DB, not entire User records, but their IDs. Provided the list of IDs and # of users being checked against is relatively manageable, something like this may be an option:

```
var minKey = keys.Min();
var maxKey = keys.Max();
var existingIds = _context.Users
    .Where(x => x.Id >= minKey && x.Id <= maxKey)
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();

var IdsNotInDb = keys.Except(existingIds);
```

This would fetch only the IDs within the range of Keys from the DB, then you can use that to compare against the list of Keys to find items in your list that don't have corresponding records. Since this is only loading the IDs, this would be just hitting the Index rather than the User table itself.

If you are instead expecting to compare very large numbers of keys against very  large numbers of users, then you would probably want to take a Temporary Table approach inserting the Keys values into an indexed temporary table, then using EF to query using a join between the user table and this new temp table.  An approach to consider for something like that can be found here: (https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/temp-tables-in-3-1/)

Comment: Thanks, but the example I gave was to simplify the problem. In actuality, it is a very long string. So I can't restrict it to a range like this. I've never seen temporary tables in Entity Framework so I'll check out that link.

Comment: If it's an operation that might be done fairly frequently, Even a staging table containing a composite key of a GUID and the Key, with the Key set up as a FK to the ID/field you want to match against in the User table. You bulk insert the array into the staging table using a unique GUID for that run (so the table can be used for multliple user sessions) then after finishing, bulk delete those staged rows using that GUID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it can be done in a single line, but here's what i suggest you do :

1. You get an array the Ids of the users that do exist in the database, then you compare it to your first array 'keys'
2. Then you find the Ids that are not in the database.

But for some reason, using Linq expressions doesn't work for me, so here's how i did it :

```
//First your prepare a query that will return users which had their Id in 
the keys array
var query = from user in Database.Users
            where keys.Contains(user.id)
            select user.id;

//Then you execute the query
var users = query.ToArray();
```

Then, you execute a query on the original list of keys, the same way you do it on your database (using Linq expressions), to find the items that do not exit in your returned array (your database) :

```
var notInUsers = keys.Where(k => !users.Contains(k)).ToArray();
```

Now, you got a new array called notInUsers which contains the Ids that were present in your 'keys' array, but which are not in your database.
Here you go, you have an optimised solution [it doesn't store your entire table (that may contain millions of records) in-memory], an you can do whatever you want with that array.
Note, if you want to work with lists instead of arrays, replace 'ToArray()' with 'ToList()'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can construct a query expression for the above case without loading the users.

```
var excludedIds = userContext
    .Where(user => !keys.Contains(user.Id))
    .Select(user => user.Id);
```

Nothing has executed at this point, and no user records have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I need. The missing keys will not be associated with *any* `Users`. I just need the keys that are not used. I don't want the users. They don't exist.

Comment: Mind that a solution using `Contains` has an upper bound (that is surprisingly low and probably lower than you think) for the number of possible entries in `keys`. EF will translate that into a WHERE .. IN .. clause, which is a) not the fastest and b) again: has a low ceiling - so don't bump your head.

Comment: @Fildor: Are you saying the `Contains` list could be truncated? Because I have some longer lists with an unrelated query. Do you know where you got this information from?

Comment: The part about the translation should be in EF docs... I'll have a look. The part about how many entries are allowed could be also mentioned there. However how many in particular will depend on the specific DBMS in use,

Comment: The Issue with huge `IN List` for TSQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks - just still looking for the EF - SQL Translation part ... cannot seem to find it, somehow.

Comment: I mean: I can see it doing it, I just _know_ I also read it somewhere and I was _pretty_ sure it was in the EF  or EF Core docs ...